# Generation of waves

Tags: waves, oscillators, vibrations

How does a wave generate from a physical phenomenon? i.e. how we can actually feel that a wave is generated through a physical process? For example I actually want to know when the spring bounces how the disturbance  caused by the vibration carries energy and propagates!

Comment: Your 1st question is very broad and seems to be asking someone to teach you all about waves and vibrations and how they propagate in materials. We cannot provide tuition, and expect you to make an effort to look for suitable resources and to study physics. Have you tried an internet search? eg http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/~cross/BOUNCE.htm

Comment: Or search for simple harmonic motion of a spring: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/shm2.html

Answer (score 2):

Clearly we can't give you a full tutorial in wave propagation here, but here's something to guide your intuition (and I encourage you to come back when you have found and absorbed some existing resources on the internet or in your text books, and ask more specific questions).

To understand elastic propagation of waves at the microscopic level, consider  a series of springs connecting point masses. I will number the springs 1 to n, with masses $m_{ij}$ between spring $i$ and spring $j$.  If you move spring #1, it will exert a force on mass $m_{12}$. As that mass starts to move, it will compress spring 2. That spring will then apply a force on mass $m_{23}$, etc. In this way, the motion applied to spring #1 will propagate through the chain.

The stronger the springs, the quicker the mass accelerates; and the heavier the mass, the slower it will accelerate. When the mass accelerates quickly, it results in rapid propagation of the wave (the information that "somebody moved the end of the chain").

All this can be analyzed mathematically - but in general the speed of propagation is going to be proportional to

$$\sqrt{\frac{\rm{elastic~term}}{\rm{{inertial~term}}}}$$

where "elastic term" is a general expression for something that expresses the resistance to change in length (spring constant, Young's modulus, etc), and "inertial term" might be mass per unit length, density, etc (depending on the application).

Comment: If you admit yourself that the question is overly broad and unclear, why do you need to answer it instead of just using your rep to force a quick close?

Comment: I take the  opposite view to Sanya, I think as the answer is useful (hopefully) to the OP, and more importantly, future readers, why not?

Comment: @count_to_10 - thank you, that was indeed my intention. This intuitive explanation is often glossed over, and can prepare the mind to better understand a more formal explanation found elsewhere. Or so I hope.